# how setTimeout works in promise in javascript?

Tags: javascript, promise, settimeout

i have a question, i don't know how setTimeout works in promise, i have to timer:

```js
const start = new Date().getTime();
function a() {
  setTimeout(() => {
    console.log('output', new Date().getTime() - start);
  }, 3000);
}

setTimeout(a, 1000);
```

output: 4000

then i change my code like this：

```js
const start = new Date().getTime();
const p13 = new Promise((resolve,reject) => {
  setTimeout(() => {
    reject(new Error('error'));
  },3000);
});

const p14 = new Promise((resolve,reject) => {
  const s = new Date().getTime();
  setTimeout(() => {
    resolve(p13);
  },1000);
});

p14.then((value) => {
  console.log(value, 'value');
}).catch((error) => {
  const end = new Date().getTime();
  console.log('output:', end - start);
});
```

output: 3000, i don't know why? it should output 4000. why 3000.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**At t = 0**

- a promise `p13` is created that starts `timeout1` with 3s waiting time
- a promise `p14` is created that starts `timeout2` with 1s waiting time

**At t = 1000**

- `timeout2` triggers the callback function, chaining `p14` with promise `p13`
- `timeout1` has traversed 1000ms

**At t = 3000**

- `timeout1` triggers the callback function, rejects promise and **output** is calculated

Let us take another example

```js
const start = new Date().getTime();
const p13 = new Promise((resolve,reject) => {
  setTimeout(() => {
    const end = new Date().getTime();
    console.log('output:', end - start);
    reject(new Error('error'));
  },3000);
});

const p14 = new Promise((resolve,reject) => {
  const s = new Date().getTime();
  setTimeout(() => {
    resolve(p13);
  },1000);
});

setTimeout(function(){
  p14.then((value) => {
    console.log(value, 'value');
  }).catch((error) => {
    console.log('error');
  });
}, 5000);
```

As you can see in the above example, the timeout of the promise `p13` gets triggered even before the the callback of `setTimeout` with 5000 ms delay is executed.

**Conclusion** - When you create a `promise` object the state of promise object is in pending state, however, the actual functionality gets triggered.

Answer (score 1):

The promises with your timeouts are asynchronous.

When you create p13, it directly starts its timeout, which is 3000.
It's not waiting for the 1000 from p14. (which is what you think)

With more details about your code expected result:

- If you put any number less than 3000 in p14, it will resolve with 300x. If you put more than 4000, then it will be rejected. (although timeout is not so accurate so it's more like around 3000 / 4000)

Answer (score 0):

When you create a new Promise, the function which you pass as the constructor's argument is executed immediately. So the `p13` timeout will invoke the rejection after 3000 ms after the Promise was created - not 3000 ms after it was passed to the `resolve` function. If you want your Promises to run one after another, you can refactor your code to something like this:

```
const start = new Date().getTime();
const p13 = () => {
    return new Promise((resolve,reject) => {
        setTimeout(() => {
            reject(new Error('error'));
        },3000);
    });
}

const p14 = new Promise((resolve,reject) => {
    const s = new Date().getTime();
    setTimeout(() => {
        resolve(p13());
    },1000);
});

p14.then((value) => {
    console.log(value, 'value');
}).catch((error) => {
    const end = new Date().getTime();
    console.log('output:', end - start);
});
```

`p13` is now a function that creates a Promise. That function is executed after 1000 ms, the new Promise is created and returned and another timeout is scheduled. The second timeout rejects the Promise after another 3000 ms, so effectively after 4000 ms after the start of the program.

Answer (score -1):

here is how you'd make it 4000

make p13 a function

resolve(p13());

now you're not starting p13 until p14 "completes"

```js
const start = new Date().getTime();
const p13 = () => new Promise((resolve,reject) => {
  setTimeout(() => {
    reject(new Error('error'));
  },3000);
});

const p14 = new Promise((resolve,reject) => {
  const s = new Date().getTime();
  setTimeout(() => {
    resolve(p13());
  },1000);
});

p14.then((value) => {
  console.log(value, 'value');
}).catch((error) => {
  const end = new Date().getTime();
  console.log('output:', end - start);
});
```